# Inserting namespaces in xml through Xsl 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have my Input XML like this -

```
<Integer xmlns="www.maths.com" xmlns:abc="www.dateTypes.com" xmlns:def="www.calculations.com">
    <ID>A1</ID>
    <abc:Date>2005-11-20</abc:Date>
    <Type>12345</Type>
    <def:Maths>Multiply</def:Maths>
</Integer>
```

I want to add namespaces through XSL 1.0 to the root element with same prefixes but with different value to it.
I want my output to be like -

```
<Integer xmlns="www.maths.com" xmlns:abc="www.dateTypes-2.0" xmlns:def="www.calculations-2.0">
    <ID>A1</ID>
    <abc:Date>2005-11-20</abc:Date>
    <Type>12345</Type>
    <def:Maths>Multiply</def:Maths>
</Integer>
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Kundan, see my answer for a **correct** and shorter solution, that is verified to work with Altova.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:abc="www.dateTypes-2.0" xmlns:def="www.calculations-2.0"
                xmlns:oldabc="www.dateTypes.com" xmlns:olddef="www.calculations.com"
                xmlns:maths="www.maths.com"
                exclude-result-prefixes="oldabc olddef maths">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="oldabc:*">
    <xsl:element name="abc:{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="olddef:*">
    <xsl:element name="def:{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@oldabc:*">
    <xsl:attribute name="abc:{local-name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@olddef:*">
    <xsl:attribute name="def:{local-name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | text()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/maths:Integer">
    <Integer xmlns="www.maths.com" xmlns:abc="www.dateTypes-2.0" xmlns:def="www.calculations-2.0">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </Integer>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When the above XSLT is run on the example input, it produces the expected result:

```
<Integer xmlns="www.maths.com" xmlns:abc="www.dateTypes-2.0" xmlns:def="www.calculations-2.0">
  <ID>A1</ID>
  <abc:Date>2005-11-20</abc:Date>
  <Type>12345</Type>
  <def:Maths>Multiply</def:Maths>
</Integer>
```

Comment: <Integer xmlns="www.maths.com">
 <ID>A1</ID>
 <abc:Date xmlns:abc="www.dateTypes.com">2005-11-20</abc:Date>
 <Type>12345</Type>
 <def:Maths xmlns:def="www.calculations.com">Multiply</def:Maths>
</Integer>

Comment: Is Integer the root node of your XML, or are there other nodes above it?

Comment: Integer is the root node of my XML.

Comment: It works on MSXSL and on XSLFiddle.  Are you using the XSLT exactly as I entered it above?  What XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: I used it as it is and I am using Altova.

Comment: Could you try adding priority="2" to the first two templates, as I have above?

Comment: I added that...still same results :(

Comment: Why are you using this  <xsl:template match="/maths:Integer">. As integer is my root element. We can use it like this  <xsl:template match="Integer">

Comment: @Kundan no, `match="Integer"` would only match elements named `Integer` that are not in a namespace, your root element is in the `www.maths.com` namespace.

Comment: The XSLT works as expected when I try it in Altova. It should also work if you remove the slash from `/maths:Integer` (please try that), but won't work if you remove the `maths:` part.

Comment: It worked with /maths:Integer part only. Thanks for the help.

Comment: JLRishe, Sorry, but this time your answer is not correct. I am not downvoting as I am sure you will correct it.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Thank you for your comment.  Would you be so kind as to point out what's wrong with it?  I realize it's not as short as yours, and I already acknowledged that it doesn't handle remapping the namespaces on attributes (though I can add that support if it's needed; the example XML didn't have any), and I have verified it in Altova, XSLFiddle, and Visual Studio.

Comment: @JLRishe, You are welcome. Just use the XML document from my answer.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I will, but in the interest of learning, I would be very interested in knowing why it is "not correct" as opposed to "longer than it needs to be". Even if I know that your approach is preferable for this particular scenario, I may make similar mistakes in the future if I don't know what I did wrong here.

Comment: @JLRishe, Why, just run your transformation on this XML document and have a look at the result.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev As I've already said, I already did so in three different XSLT engines, and all produced the expected result (unless you're referring to the XML declaration, which is trivial).  I just did this one more time to make sure, and added the result to my post.

Comment: @JLRishe, I don't see anything added -- please, just copy and paste the XML document from my answer.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev As I already said when I originally posted my answer, and here in the comments, I am aware that my XSLT does not change the namespace on attributes. If that's why you are telling me that my answer is not correct, then you are telling me something that I already acknowledged long before you said it. Changing attribute namespaces was not something that the asker indicated a need for, either explicitly or implicity, but I will go ahead and modify my XSLT so that they are taken into account.

Comment: @JLRishe, Yes, this is the problem I see. Typically (and I believe this is the case here) a question doesn't contain the real XML document, but a simplified one. We need to give a solution that would be usable for the real document, which we are not in a position to guess. I apologize if this may seem as too "punctual", but I believe this is important.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Yes, I agree it's important to go beyond the stated request when possible.  I figured leaving off the attribute handling and asking the asker if he needed it was a safe move, because even most XML that uses namespaces has its attributes in the null namespace (XSLT itself being a prime example of this). I do appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0):

**A shorter solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:abc="www.dateTypes-2.0" xmlns:def="www.calculations-2.0">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vNS" select=
   "document('')/*/namespace::*[name()='abc' or name()='def']"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vDefNS" select="/*/namespace::*[not(name())]"/>

 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}">
       <xsl:copy-of select="$vDefNS"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[name()=local-name()]">
     <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{$vDefNS}">
       <xsl:copy-of select="$vNS"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
     </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied to the following XML document** (the same as the provided one, but added an attribute to make it more representative):

```
<Integer xmlns="www.maths.com"
 xmlns:abc="www.dateTypes.com" xmlns:def="www.calculations.com">
    <ID>A1</ID>
    <abc:Date>2005-11-20</abc:Date>
    <Type abc:x="1">12345</Type>
    <def:Maths>Multiply</def:Maths>
</Integer>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<Integer xmlns="www.maths.com" xmlns:abc="www.dateTypes-2.0" xmlns:def="www.calculations-2.0">
   <ID>A1</ID>
   <abc:Date>2005-11-20</abc:Date>
   <Type abc:x="1">12345</Type>
   <def:Maths>Multiply</def:Maths>
</Integer>
```